# Define GraphQL object type in .graphql files not working

Tags: typescript, graphql, typegraphql, graphql-tools, graphql-codegen

I'm trying to make a mutation in type-graphql and one of the arguments is Object so:

```js
@Mutation(() => Boolean)
async createProduct(
    @Arg('name', () => String) name: string,
    @Arg('price', () => Int) price: number,
    @Arg('images', () => [InputImages]) images: [ImagesArray],
) {
    // Code
}
```

So i made an input type for argument "images":

```js
@InputType()
class InputImages {
  @Field(() => String)
  filename: string;
}
```

And an Object type:

```js
@ObjectType()
export class ImagesArray {
    @Field(() => String)
    filename: string
}
```

Now i am trying to use GraphQL Code Generator and i need to write queries and mutations on client side as a .graphql file extension, so i have:

```js
mutation CreateProduct(
    $name: String!
    $price: Int!
    $images: [ImagesArray]!
) {
    createProduct(
        name: $name
        price: $price
        images: $images
    );
}
```

And now when i try to run **"npm run gen"** says:

> **GraphQLDocumentError: Unknown type "ImagesArray".**

I tried to add on top:

```js
type ImagesArray {
    filename: String
}
```

Does not work again, any idea?

Answer (score 0):

1. You don't need `ImagesArray` type in args:

```
@Arg('images', () => [InputImages]) images: InputImages[],
```

2. Update your mutation type name:

```
mutation CreateProduct(
    $name: String!
    $price: Int!
    $images: [InputImages!]!
) {
  # ...
}
```